# .load() callback function doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this piece of code in my wordpress theme to load the pages in it, check it:

```
($j for no conflict)

$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#main-nav a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $jloca = this.href;
        $j("#content").load($jloca '#main-content');
        alert('****');

    });
});
```

It loads the `#main-content` from the page I have specified in the `href` on my `#main-nav a`.
It loads inside the `#content` OK.

But my alert does not work!

Well, I don't want to alert, I want to do some CSS changes but alert is for testing.

I also tried it as a callback function, see:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#main-nav a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $jloca = this.href;
        $j("#content").load($jloca '#main-content', function () {
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
    });
});
```

Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: need to return `false` within an `<a>` click handler so browser doesn't open href, or use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @charlietfl There is yet a event.preventDefault() in OP's code.

Comment: @dystroy sure is..my bad, not sure why I missed it first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile.

Change

```
$j("#content").load($jloca '#main-content');
```

to

```
$j("#content").load($jloca + ' #main-content');
```

Note that you should first look at the console to see those errors. I'd suggest you to read about [the developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: i will, thank you. Pls, should i clear #content before .load() anything on it? I say this because its loading the full page inside it, not only #main-content as i'd like to

Comment: +1 for notes on developer tools which are great for finding localized issues like this.

Comment: No, you don't have to clear it. But is there an element with id main-content in the page ? And did you put the space as in my code ?

Comment: Lols, thats a magical space you got there ;) fixed totally. Developer tools will be my best friends now Actually i was trying to find them here

Comment: Not totally magical. It's explained in [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/) : *" If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded"*.